# Stabilizing a ceiling fan light cover

Tags: ceiling-fan

I just got a ceiling fan light cover (ceiling fan didn't have anything covering lights when moved in).

Here are all the parts:
[image]

The problem is the light cover is not stable at all:
https://youtu.be/mcO8tyKej58

**How are you supposed to stabilize these things**?

Comment: Can you post a pic of the fan without the cover.  There might be a missing piece still.

Comment: @Tyson Can add a pic later, but there's nothing there. Just the rod to screw the small piece into.

Comment: I suspect there should be another nut and washer that goes onto the rod first then the glass and the exterior decorative pieces you do have.  Those would sandwich the glass.